# htaccess not working properly on centos

Tags: php, .htaccess, centos

I am working on a website on a centos vps and I have this  htaccess :

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ abc/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) abc/$1 [L]
```

When I delete the last line the 500 error is disappearing but at that time of course I am not able to use the files in that abc directory properly. What is the problem with this last line ?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules is likely looping infinitely.

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^((?!app/webtoot/).*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L,NC]
```